# How can I get custom class variables to display onString() value when debugging?

Tags: android, debugging

When I am debugging, stop at a break-point and 'hover' over in-scope variables in the source code, a pop-up window displays the variable class members and a variable string representation.  If I have a variables window open and click on in-scope variables, the window displays the same variable class members and variable string representation.

1. I have local variables of class Bundle, String, TextView and SplitValueRow [a custom class]
2. When I hover over the variable bundle, the string representation displayed is the string returned by the Bundle class override of inherited toString() method.
3. When I hover over the variable string, the string representation displayed is the string returned by the String class override of inherited toString() method.
4. When I hover over the variable textView, the string representation displayed is the string returned by inherited class [Object] toString() method.  This class ***DOES NOT*** override the inherited toString() method.
5. When I hover over the variable splitClassRow, the string representation displayed is the string returned by inherited class [Object] toString() method.  This class ***DOES*** override the inherited toString() method.

My stripped down custom class overridden toString() method:

```
  @Override
  public synchronized String toString() {
    String s = new String();
    s.concat(twValueRight.getText().toString());        
    return s;
  }
```

The question:  Why doesn't my custom class overridden toString() method work in the same manner as the Bundle and String overridden toString() methods when hovering and in variables window?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the actual code you are using, you have a problem with concatenation. String concatenation does not work like that in Java. You are returning an empty string.

Use:

```
@Override
public synchronized String toString() {
  return twValueRight.getText().toString();        
}
```

Or:

```
@Override
public synchronized String toString() {
  String s = new String();      
  s = s.concat(twValueRight.getText().toString());       
  return s; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  concat is not a very efficient/elegant way to build strings.  I was trying for a 'quick and dirty' solution and I got my just rewards!